# Как прервать закрытие Активити на Android java?

Tags: java, android, activity

Как мне сделать чтобы при попытке закрыть Активити, кнопкой назад или как ещё, пользователю задавался вопрос "Хочет ли он сохранить документ" (Да,Нет,Отмена). В случае (Да,Нет) соответственно сохранить или нет, а в случае (Отмена) продолжить оставаться в этой Активити, т.е. отменить её закрытие? Я пытался вызывать Диалог в onOptionsItemSelected(), но это работает только для кнопки назад в Toolbar, если нажать кнопку назад в нижней панели, то это уже не срабатывает. Пытался отловить в onPause(), но как отменить уже начавшееся закрытие не понятно, диалог появляется и Активити тут же закрывается.

Comment: Используйте alertdialog

Comment: Переопределите метод `onBackPressed`! И делайте свои проверки там.

Comment: Никак, но программист обязан (или это очень желательно) восстановить состояние активности после перезапуска.

Answer (score 0):

Вот рыба на Котлине для такого случая

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this, R.style.DialogTheme)
        .setTitle(R.string.exit_application)
        .setMessage(R.string.exit_application_message)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes) { dialog, _ ->
            dialog.cancel()
            // save your work
            finish()
        }
        .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.no) { dialog, _ ->
            dialog.cancel()
            finish()
        }
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel) { dialog, _ ->
            dialog.cancel()
        }
        .create().show()
}
```

Comment: а как же на счет "или как еще"?

Comment: А "как еще" никак. Там нет возможности вопросы пользователю задавать. И прервать процесс там никак нельзя. Это совсем другая история и с этой ее нет смысла обьединять.

Comment: Так это цитата из вопроса, выходит ответ не подходит.